# Search for email in multiple tables for different databases

Tags: mysql, database, search, union-all

I asked this question before but I need some more help as I am a complete noob to mysql and phpmyadmin. I have some big databases that i have uploaded to my local host and plan to use them like it was leakedsource. I was told to use this to query different tables but I have one question. In this code **where do I put what I want to search for?**

```
SELECT option_value
FROM `database1`.`table1`
WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT option_value2
FROM `database2`.`table2`
WHERE ..;
```

Comment: This site messed with the format of the text at the bottom

Comment: "Leakedsource"? Also why can't you just aggregate all the interesting values into a table using `INSERT INTO x SELECT y FROM z` repeatedly?

Comment: What do you want to search? Data in tables `table1` and `table2`? 
You can append your condition after `where` like `where name like 'John%' `